Convergence to unique stationary distribution for SDEs and Markov processes
I am interested in understanding the behavior of solutions to stochastic differential equations (SDEs) and continuous-time Markov processes with constant coefficients. Specifically, I would like to know under what conditions the solution to a constant-coefficient autonomous SDE (or more generally, a continuous-time Markov process with uncountable states) converges to a unique stationary distribution as time tends to infinity.
I am particularly curious about this topic because I want to understand the differences between SDEs and ordinary differential equations (ODEs). If the only difference introduced by the random term in an SDE is related to additional computations involving randomness, it might seem rather trivial. However, if the introduction of randomness leads to significantly different properties compared to the original ODE, that would be quite fascinating.
One specific aspect I am interested in is whether it is common for an ODE to exhibit chaotic and irregular behavior as time goes to infinity, while the corresponding SDE converges to a unique stationary distribution. I previously asked a related question on MSE regarding whether this kind of interest can be applied to statistical mechanics (link: SDEs and irreversibility in statistical mechanics).
I believe that for a constant-coefficient autonomous SDE, the Markov property may imply convergence to a unique stationary distribution. For discrete-time, finite-state Markov chains, the conditions for convergence to a unique stationary distribution are quite weak (e.g., as long as every entry in the state transition matrix is strictly positive). I wonder if similar conditions apply to continuous-time, uncountable-state Markov processes, although I expect the situation to be more complex.
For example, Brownian motion does not converge to a stationary distribution, which is different from the discrete, finite-state case. I am unsure where to find results related to sufficient and necessary conditions for convergence to a unique stationary distribution in this context. I am also curious if the Krein–Rutman theorem, the infinite-dimensional analog of the Perron–Frobenius theorem, is relevant here or if stochastic dynamical systems are the appropriate framework to study these questions.
Any insights or references on this topic would be greatly appreciated!

You can use some integration by parts on the infinitesimal generator to get some naive classification of stationary distributions under the assumption that the stationary distribution admits a density. For example, if $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold without boundary and the SDE is just that generated by the Laplace-Beltrami operator, then $u$ is simply a harmonic function, and in particular the stationary distribution is just the volume measure.
As I understand it, there is a pretty robust literature about invariant measures for SDEs.

I think this question is interesting, but rather open-ended. A few comments: (i) Yes, adding noise tends to have a regularizing effect on solutions and can cause convergence to equilibrium in various cases, but whether this happens depends a lot on the precise assumptions. (ii) The situation in continuous time differs from the situation in discrete time (also in finite dimensions) since continuous time has, under sufficient regularity assumptions, the consequence that no periodic orbits exist. [...]

[...] (iii) Yes, the spectral theory of positive operators (Perron-Frobenius, Krein-Rutman, various versions thereof) is one useful tool to study the long-term behaviour of Markov processes. There are, of coure, also other tools (which I'm personally less familiar with, but which are probably more prominent in the stochastic analysis community).
